# Как указать корневую директорию в PhoneGap?

Tags: html, phonegap

В общем эта проблема касается всех подгружаемых ресурсов(js, css, картинки)
На примере .css пытался сделать так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
```

Но все равно, приписывая "./" получается не то: картинки не грузятся, js и ссылки тоже не работают, css вроде грузится, но если смотреть через браузер, то ничего нет.

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2):

В общем правильно надо было писать вот так(слэш без точки):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
```

Всем хорошей ночи =)